# c++11 - zero-initi of members insted of default-init

Tags: c++, zero-initialization, default-initialization

In the below code, I expect members of `a` being inited with gargabe as they are not mentioned in the members-init-list of the called constructor (with two `int` parameters). Instead, I'm constantly getting `0` in both `i` and `j` of `a`, `b` and `c` and I am failing to see why. Could anybody please point me in the right direction?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


class A {
    public:
        int i;
        int j;
        A() = delete;
        A(int a, int b) { std::cout << "VOLOLO!" << std::endl; };
};

int
smear_stack(int p)
{
    int j = p++;
    int a[500] = {};
    for(int i = 0; i < 499; i++) {
        a[i] = ++j;
    }
    std::cout << j << std::endl;
    return ++j;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 2;
    i = smear_stack(++i);

    A a  (i, 32 );
    std::cout << "a is " << a.i << " " << a.j << std::endl;

    A b = { a };
    std::cout << "b is " << b.i << " " << b.j << std::endl;

    A c = { a.i, a.j };
    std::cout << "c is " << c.i << " " << c.j << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: [Try it with a different compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/i9RG5pFQqHIUHdIG) (or perhaps, optimisation level).  And turn optimisation  on and you'll get a bunch of compiler warnings.  You can't rely on uninitialised variables to contain _any_ particular value, that's just not how things work.

Comment: All of this is not legal code, but in practice, you are smearing the stack below the current stack frame.  The space for `a`, `b`, and `c` is probably reserved on entry to the function, so the call to `smear_stack` doesn't affect them.

Comment: @PaulSanders hey, thanks for the answer! So, accessing an indeterminate value is UB, so i cannot reason about what is going on? In my tests with wandbox that were only `c` members being all 0 with multiple versions of compilers.

Comment: @user3188445 thanks for pointing the thing about frame, that one eluded me. I tried to call it from other functions with no avail to change the contents, but I guess UB is UB)

Comment: @AntonTretyakov Not really, no, there's not really any point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `i` and `j` fields that you are accessing are, indeed, uninitialized.  However, you are smearing the wrong part of the stack.  It just so happens that on most OSes, the stack is initially all zeros.  It even used to be common in C (long ago) to assume that automatic variables in `main` were zero-initialized.

To see that the memory is indeed uninitialized, it suffices to put something else there.  Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
    int i;
    int j;
    A() = delete;
    A(int a, int b) { std::cout << "VOLOLO!" << std::endl; };
};

union U {
    int is[2];
    A a;
    U() : is{3,4} {}
};

int
main()
{
    U u;
    std::construct_at(&u.a, 5, 6);
    std::cout << u.a.i << ", " << u.a.j << std::endl;
    // output:
    // VOLOLO!
    // 3, 4
}
```

Comment: This is a great trick, thank you for pointing it out! But isn't this kind of type punning UB in c++?

Comment: I don't think so, because `std::construct_at` begins the lifetime of `u.a`.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union

Comment: Ahh, so reading from `is` is now UB! Thank you once again, that was really useful!